# Stream is not filled when using a MemoryStream for PdfWriter output from iTextSharp

Tags: .net, stream, itext, filestream, memorystream

I have the following issue.

This code works fine

```
private void ModifyAndSavePDF(Stream sourceFile, string text)
{
    using (var pdfWriterStream = new FileStream(@"d:/temp/test.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
        var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfWriterStream);
        document.Open();
        for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
            //some more PDF editing stuff here. Not relevant.
        }
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

This works fine. The `sourceFile` stream contains around 200Kb and the saved pdf looks exactly as I expect. One thing I note is that before `document.Close()` the length of the `pdfWriterStream` stream is only around 800 bytes.

My problem is that I don't want to save this to a file on the disk, I would like to have the output as a MemoryStream instead. That however I can't get to work as I expect. My first attempt was this:

```
private Stream ModifyAndSavePDF(Stream sourceFile, string text)
{
    using (var pdfWriterStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
        var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfWriterStream);
        document.Open();
        for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
            //some more PDF editing stuff here. Not relevant.
        }
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    return pdfWriterStream;
}
```

This won't work of course, since when I call `document.Close()`, the `pdfWriterStream`is also disposed, and I can't read the contents of the stream.

Second attempt:

```
private Stream ModifyAndSavePDF(Stream sourceFile, string text)
{
    var result = new MemoryStream();
    using (var pdfWriterStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
        var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfWriterStream);
        document.Open();
        for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
            //some more PDF editing stuff here. Not relevant.
        }
        pdfWriterStream.Position = 0;
        pdfWriterStream.CopyTo(result);
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This gets me the problem as the first code listed. `pdfWriterStream` at this point only consist of around 800 bytes, and when copied to `result` that also only get's these 800 bytes and not the entire file.

So it seems like `document.Close()` flushes the file to the buffer, and then disposes it. So I think I need to do some operation before I copy the `pdfWriterStream` to `result`, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to *return a `MemoryStream` object from a method*, don't put it into a `using` clause in that very method: When leaving that `using` block, the stream object is disposed, so the caller of your method gets a closed stream which he won't be happy about.

Second, if you don't want the stream a `PdfWriter` writes to to be closed when the associated `Document` is closed, simply set the `PdfWriter` attribute `CloseStream` to `false`.

Thus:

```cs
private Stream ModifyAndSavePDF(Stream sourceFile, string text)
{
    var pdfWriterStream = new MemoryStream();
    var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
    var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfWriterStream);
    writer.CloseStream = false;
    document.Open();
    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        document.NewPage();
        var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
        var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        //some more PDF editing stuff here. Not relevant.
    }
    document.Close();
    reader.Close();

    return pdfWriterStream;
}
```

As an aside, you do not need to close the `PdfWriter`, it is implicitly closed when the associated `Document` is closed.

And another aside, at first glance your method looks like you copy some original PDF and apply some changes to it. Usually (depending on the exact changes you want to apply, that is) one should do this using a `PdfStamper`, not a plain `PdfWriter`.

Comment: Yes. I understand that having the returned stream inside a using statement is a poor solution, but my problem was that the stream was closed when the writer/document was closed, and not when the using block was exited. But `CloseStream = false` is the missing piece of my puzzle here, and solves my problem, so thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also, thanks for the tips in both asides. I didn't know about the PdfStamper, so I'm absolutely going to check that out.